# Error on simple html dom url

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i am using Simple html dom where i get this problem:

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://forums.xxxxx.co.il/viewtopic.php?f=1015&amp;t=14635609) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\forums_walla\simple_html_dom.php on line 76`

I think the problem is `&amp;` where is should be only `&`?

Does anyone know what to do? or what should be fixed?

btw code goes like this:

```
$href1 = "http://forums.xxxx.co.il/".$topic_page_href; // where $topic_page_href contains the link to next page as --> viewtopic.php?f=1015&t=14635609 which was scrapped from a page)
$topic_page = file_get_html($href1);
```

and if i do

```
$href1 = "http://forums.xxxx.co.il/viewtopic.php?f=1015&t=14635609
$topic_page = file_get_html($href1);
```

everything is just fine.

### i have been trying to solve it since yester but nothing. Hope someone has the solution to it. thx in advance :)

Please ask anything thats required.

Comment: try `url_decode($topic_page_href)` before appending it...

Comment: @khez yes.. simple html dom uses it instead of file_get_contents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the string into

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

[Documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: ahh.. thnk you so much it seem to be the solution.. Thnk you again.